# Помогите расставить знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Истинная честность живет часто как жемчужина в грязной устричной раковине.

Answer (score 1):

Истинная честность живет часто **как жемчужина в грязной устричной раковине.**

Сравнительный оборот с союзом КАК не обособляется, так как в качестве обстоятельства входит основное сообщение, тесная связь обстоятельства со сказуемым.